# I want to Rebuild data table from a sorted table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2000

Okay first a little bit of background, I've inherited maintaining a Database on MSSQL 2000.

In the Database there's a massive collection of interconnected tables, through Foreign keys.

What I'm attempting to do is to rebuild each table in a sorted fashion that will eliminate gaps in the IDENT column of the table.

On one table in particular I have the following columns:

RL_ID, RL_FK_RaidID, RL_FK_MemberID, RL_FK_ItemID, RL_ItemValue, RL_Notes, RL_IsUber, RL_IsWishItem, RL_LootModifier, RL_WishItemValue, RL_WeightedLootValue

It uses RL_ID as the IDENT column which currently reports 32620 by using DBCC CHECKIDENT (Table)
There is, however, only 12128 rows of information in this table.

So I tried a simple script to copy all the information in a sorted fashion into a new table:

```
INSERT INTO Table_1

SELECT     RL_ID, RL_FK_RaidID, RL_FK_MemberID, RL_FK_ItemID, RL_ItemValue, RL_Notes, RL_IsUber, RL_IsWishItem, RL_LootModifier, RL_WishItemValue, RL_WeightedLootValue

FROM         RaidLoot

ORDER BY RL_ID
```

---

Then Delete all the rows from the source table with:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE (RaidLoot)
```

Verify the IDENT is 1 with:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (RaidLoot)
```

---

Now copy the Data back into the Original table from Row 1 to the end:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT RaidLoot ON

INSERT INTO RaidLoot (RL_ID, RL_FK_RaidID, RL_FK_MemberID, RL_FK_ItemID, RL_ItemValue, RL_Notes, RL_IsUber, RL_IsWishItem, RL_LootModifier, RL_WishItemValue, RL_WeightedLootValue)

SELECT RL_ID, RL_FK_RaidID, RL_FK_MemberID, RL_FK_ItemID, RL_ItemValue, RL_Notes, RL_IsUber, RL_IsWishItem, RL_LootModifier, RL_WishItemValue, RL_WeightedLootValue

FROM         Table_1

ORDER BY RL_ID

SET IDENTITY_INSERT RaidLoot OFF
```

---

Now verify that I only have the 12128 rows of data:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (RaidLoot)
```

---

(Note: I end up with 32620 again since it never did renumber the RL_ID, it just put them back into the same spots leaving the gaps).  So where / how can I get it to Renumber the RL_ID column starting from 1 so that when it writes the data back to the original table I don't have the gaps?

The only other solution I can see is a heartache process of Manually changing each row RL_ID in the Table_1 before I write it back to the Original table.  While this isn't impossible.  I have another table that has approx 306,000 rows of data, but the IDENT report lists out as 450,123, so I'm hoping there is an easier way to automate the renumbering process.

Comment: Most likely RL_ID is referenced by other tables in the schema, In order to change it you would need to update those references. This can be quite a chore. What is wrong with leaving the gaps?

Comment: @Andreas, my thoughts exactly.  While I could appreciate wanting to start over and using a min int opposed to 0 to double the records.  Either way, if you're approaching the limit 2,147,483,647, you probably have other problems to worry about - other than non-contiguous numbers

Comment: @DanAndrews, Okay unless I have to add up all the individual IDENT columns, I'm no where close to the 2,147,483,647. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really have to do this (seems like a great waste of time to me), you will have to adjust all of the foreign key references as well.

Consider the strategy of adding a NewID column for each table and populate the new column sequentially. Then you can use this NewID column in the queries needed to adjust the foreign keys. Very messy nonetheless unless you can come up with a consistent pattern to do so.

Since you can query the metadata to determine foreign keys, etc. this is certainly possible, and definitely should be considered seriously if you really do have lots of tables.

ADDED

```
There is a simple way to populate the NewID column

declare @id int
set @id = 0
update MyTable set NewID=@id, @id=@id+1
```

It is not obvious that this works, but it does.

Comment: @Gary Thanks Gary, appreciate the suggestion

Comment: Added way to populate newid column

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it has to do with RL_ID being referenced by other tables in the schema - if I set up a single table test, the identity will always show up as the max number in the identity field:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), other VARCHAR(1))

INSERT INTO #temp
        ( other )
VALUES  (  -- id - int
          'a'  -- other - varchar(1)
          ),('b'),('c'),('d'),('e')

SELECT *
FROM #temp

SELECT *
INTO #holder
FROM #temp
WHERE other = 'C'

TRUNCATE TABLE #temp

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #temp ON

INSERT INTO #temp
        ( id, other )
SELECT  id ,
        other
FROM #holder

DBCC CHECKIDENT (#temp)

DROP TABLE #temp
DROP TABLE #holder
```

So your new identity is 32620 because that is the MAX(RL_ID)